# i am a trying to open a file with .ml extension

Tags: python, machine-learning

[click here to view the file](https://github.com/DheerajPranav/Student-Placement-Prediction-using-DECISION-TREE--/blob/master/model.ml)
after opening the window click on view raw then the file will get downloaded as model.ml. The file was opening in notepad++ but the code is not at all readable 
It was saved as model.ml it consisted some code regarding decision tree algorithm
i don't know how to open and edit it according to my format

Comment: can you share the file?

Comment: .ml files are normally F# files

Comment: its probably a trained ML model. read it with the library which created the model. they usually have functions to save and read models

Comment: yes the file is saved as model.ml in prediction of student placement code it consisted some code regarding decision tree